# Are there different ways to post to user's wall and ask for permissions?

Tags: api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall, feed

I've been checking some app, which is configured and loaded as page tab.

This app ask for the corresponding permissions, publish_stream, etc. but the permissions dialog open as a lightbox, without leaving the app/page/tab. Look

[image: different way to ask permission]

After giving permissions, I vote a picture and the app publishes into my wall as if I have written a comment into the post... "*I've voted for ... blablabla*"

[image: another way to post to wall]

- Am I missing some parameter in the $facebook->api("$user/feed") api call?
- Should I call another api function?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can’t see what your actual question is. But posting _anything_ that has not been typed in by the user themselves is against Facebook’s Policies. If you want to notify others that your user has voted on something somewhere, you should use Open Graph actions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this as 2 questions:

1.) How to get a lightbox
2.) how to autopost a message or action

1.) The lightbox dialogs are something you can invoke with the js sdk -> FB.ui IF you have basic permissions. The only exception i found was Facebook tab apps! :D

2.) What i can make of the screenshot is just a simple post to a users /[user]/feed on the graph, to achieve this when someone is offline : https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ ... actions are pretty much the same, except that you post to [user]/actions

cheers

Comment: Basically you can get the “overlay” version of the dialogs for anything that runs _inside_ facebook.com – so canvas or page tab app (and it works for the latter as well without problems, and should even do so automatically, without having to explicitly specify it via the `display` parameter). Of course these dialogs only work inside facebook.com, because on external sites the user would have no way of telling whether this was a genuine FB dialog (since you can overlay your own page with _anything_ you want) – and that would be especially bad for the login dialog.

Comment: The iframe dialog is only possible with a valid access token, so FB.login on canvas will popup. this wont happen on the page ... As soon as you have a valid access token you can load iframe dialogs -> also outside of facebook

Comment: 1. this modal window over a facebook.com page is not the same as the iframe version (display=iframe) of a dialog, 2. this modal version of the login dialog works fine for page tab apps without an access token, so I can’t see why it shouldn’t on canvas, 3. the login dialog can _never_ be called in an iframe (again, iframe _version_ of the dialog, not modal _over_ an app-on-facebook iframe).

Comment: Cbroe -> about 2.) -> i've never seen it!  how to force this modal mode? FB.ui?

Comment: FB.ui and FB.login both support this modal mode for canvas/page tab apps, via `display:async` – which is the default nowadays, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#common

Comment: Thanks both Miguel and CBroe. Must submit bounty. I see you don't need it CBroe so I'll award 2 Miguel :P